# "ReferenceError: ss is not defined" when creating a Room Reservation System

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I'm having a few issues running a room reservation script. I am working in Google Apps Script editor, and have opened/linked the project directly from the spreadsheet I am trying to work from, but continue to get the error. In the project details, it lists the correct spreadsheet at the Container.

The specific error I am getting is:

> ReferenceError: ss is not defined (line 6, file "Code")

Complete code is below:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

// Calendars to output appointments to
var calHY15 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('case.edu_2tesjqf46sr95oijgkm6hp3m68@group.calendar.google.com');
var calHY19 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('case.edu_r1pgkj7ad2p4ft0hmn1l9b0e6s@group.calendar.google.com');
var calHY209 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('c_gljq01lfj2le6hbkhhpp7b0mk8@group.calendar.google.com');
var calHY210 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('c_18e8ho6pho29i9h2hv0opokg68@group.calendar.google.com');
var calHY211 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('c_mpse3jk6vsod5brkgnsll1c3ic@group.calendar.google.com');
var calHY212 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('c_4mio4552pcl1tl6mujtt53p7u0@group.calendar.google.com');
var calDenison158 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('c_t8gp6p91isg7ind6ig7g6lje4k@group.calendar.google.com');
var calDenison159 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('c_tv0o3h9d748g1o7ko4pqu5c3hs@group.calendar.google.com');
var calDenison180 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('c_632sqa2iq8advmgt8c1b029gno@group.calendar.google.com');
var calDenison182 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('c_rgoev0i3gaaij7jkisl8ukg5q4@group.calendar.google.com');
var calDenison184 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('c_on87ln97eqb5935mipvrjgu3kk@group.calendar.google.com');
var calDenison186 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('c_tqaur8mjsij30kp6iqpm61fkus@group.calendar.google.com');
var calPercussionStudio = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('c_a9otk48p9298mtofkhsp7somes@group.calendar.google.com');

// Create an object from user submission
function Submission(){
  var row = lastRow;
  this.timestamp = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
  this.name = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
  this.email = sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue();
  this.reason = sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue();
  this.date = sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue();
  this.time = sheet.getRange(row, 7).getValue();
  this.duration = sheet.getRange(row, 8).getValue();
  this.room = sheet.getRange(row, 9).getValue();
  // Info not from spreadsheet
  this.roomInt = this.room.replace(/\D+/g, '');
  this.status;
  this.dateString = (this.date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + this.date.getDate() + '/' + this.date.getYear();
  this.timeString = this.time.toLocaleTimeString();
  this.date.setHours(this.time.getHours());
  this.date.setMinutes(this.time.getMinutes());
  this.calendar = eval('cal' + String(this.roomInt));
  return this;
}

// Use duration to create endTime variable
function getEndTime(request){
  request.endTime = new Date(request.date);
  switch (request.duration){
    case "30 minutes":
      request.endTime.setMinutes(request.date.getMinutes() + 45);
      request.endTimeString = request.endTime.toLocaleTimeString();
      break;
    case "1 hour":
      request.endTime.setMinutes(request.date.getMinutes() + 75);
      request.endTimeString = request.endTime.toLocaleTimeString();
      break;
    
  }
}

// Check for appointment conflicts
function getConflicts(request){
  var conflicts = request.calendar.getEvents(request.date, request.endTime);
  if (conflicts.length < 1) {
    request.status = "Approve";
  } else {
    request.status = "Conflict";
  }
}

function draftEmail(request){
  request.buttonLink = "https://forms.gle/Eq8qHWGVgzpahbFE9";
  request.buttonText = "New Request";
  switch (request.status) {
    case "Approve":
      request.subject = "Confirmation: " + request.room + " Reservation for " + request.dateString;
      request.header = "Confirmation";
      request.message = "Your room reservation has been scheduled.";
      break;
    case "Conflict":
      request.subject = "Conflict with " + request.room + "Reservation for " + request.dateString;
      request.header = "Conflict";
      request.message = "There is a scheduling conflict. Please pick another room or time."
      request.buttonText = "Reschedule";
      break;
  }
}

function updateCalendar(request){
  var event = request.calendar.createEvent(
    request.name,
    request.date,
    request.endTime
    )
}

function sendEmail(request){
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: request.email,
    subject: request.header,
    htmlBody: makeEmail(request)
  })
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn).setValue("Sent: " + request.status);
}

// --------------- main --------------------

function main(){
  var request = new Submission();
  getEndTime(request);
  getConflicts(request);
  draftEmail(request);
  if (request.status == "Approve") updateCalendar(request);
  sendEmail(request);
}
```

There is a separate email script I have not included on this to save room. All scopes have been approved, I am the owner of the spreadsheet and calendars involved, and a trigger as been set up to run the main when a form is submitted.

Comment: The error is correct. You didn't define `ss`. Please conduct some research into what a "ReferenceError" is in JavaScript.

Comment: @Simmer: In this case Java should not be replaced by JavaScript as this is part of the OP knowledge (or lack of it) about the problem. If you want to "correct" them, post a comment or answer. By the other hand the [tag:calendar] should be replaced by [tag:google-calendar-api]

Answer (score 2):

To fix the error replace

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

by

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

Notes:

The Google Apps Script editor uses JavaScript, not Java.

Your code might have other errors. If you were not able to find the above fix by your self, you might should spend sometime learning about how variables work in JavaScript and how to debug code in the Google Apps Script editor.

Your code is using the global scope to call Google Apps Script classes. This might make the code hard to debug.

Comment: Thank you! I was going off of a tutorial video that typed in the script this way and worked there, which is where my confusion came from seeing it work in another instance and thought it was a more complex issue!